# Recursively create objects

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm trying run my method recursively. In each iteration of method I create new `ArrayList` and fill it some values and check some condition in `if` operator. If it's true, will run this method again. If it's false, I want exit of current iteration of method and work in previous iteration of method with previous copy of `ArrayList`. In practice, when I get false in condition and go in previous iteration of my method, I work with same `ArrayList`. And it's bad.

How do I create each instance of `ArrayList` for each iteration of method and when follow back in previous method work with instance of that iteration of `ArrayList`?

My code:

```
    private List<List<String>> letsTry(List<List<ProbableValue>>
probableValues, List<List<String>> data) {

     List<List<String>> copyOfData = new ArrayList<List<String>>(data);
     List<List<ProbableValue>> copyOfProbableValues = 
                           new ArrayList<List<ProbableValue>>(probableValues);

    ProbableValue minPV = getMinPV(copyOfProbableValues);

    Set<String> pValues = new HashSet<String>(minPV.getProbableValues());
    int i = minPV.getI();
    int j = minPV.getJ();


    for (String v : pValues) {

        if (checker.canSetOnTable(copyOfProbableValues, minPV)) {
            if (!SUtils.isItsNumber(copyOfData.get(i).get(j))) {
                copyOfData.get(i).set(j, v);

          copyOfProbableValues.get(i).get(j).getProbableValues().clear();
          checker.removeProbableValue(copyOfProbableValues, v, i, j);

            }
          letsTry(new ArrayList<List<ProbableValue>>(copyOfProbableValues),
                    new ArrayList<List<String>>(copyOfData));

        }

    }

    return copyOfData;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're creating a shallow copy of a List containing Lists. Therefore only the references of the nested Lists will be copied. If you want a full depth copy, you got to do something like this:

```
List<List<String>> copyOfData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    copyOfData.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    for (String s : data.get(i)) {
        copyOfData.get(i).add(s);
    }
}

List<List<ProbableValue>> copyOfProbableData = new ArrayList<List<ProbableValue>>();
for (int i = 0; i < probableValues.size(); i++) {
    copyOfProbableData.add(new ArrayList<ProbableValue>());
    for (ProbableValue p : probableValues.get(i)) {
        ProbableValue pNew = new ProbableValue();

        // copy your object here

        copyOfProbableData.get(i).add(pNew);
    }
}
```